# Bluetooth Headset: HSP/HFP not working

Tags: fedora, audio, pulseaudio, bluetooth, bluez

I've got a Bluetooth headset (Sony WH-1000XM3) which works perfectly with PulseAudio as long as I only use it as an output device. Changing the Bluetooth profile in pavucontrol works for everything (SBC, LDAC, aptX HD, aptX and AAC) except HSP/HFP. PulseAudio outputs the following error when this happens:

```
I: [pulseaudio] protocol-native.c: Application "PulseAudio-Lautstärkeregler" requests card profile change. card = bluez_card.38_18_4C_6D_C9_22, profile = headset_head_unit
I: [pulseaudio] core.c: default_sink: bluez_sink.38_18_4C_6D_C9_22.a2dp_sink -> alsa_output.usb-BEHRINGER_UMC204HD_192k-00.analog-surround-40
I: [pulseaudio] source-output.c: Freeing output 3 "Ausschlagsserkennung"
I: [bluetooth] bluez5-util.c: Transport /org/bluez/hci0/dev_38_18_4C_6D_C9_22/sep5/fd13 released
I: [pulseaudio] sink.c: Freeing sink 1 "bluez_sink.38_18_4C_6D_C9_22.a2dp_sink"
I: [pulseaudio] source.c: Freeing source 3 "bluez_sink.38_18_4C_6D_C9_22.a2dp_sink.monitor"
I: [pulseaudio] backend-native.c: doing connect
E: [pulseaudio] backend-native.c: connect(): Function not implemented
```

On start also

```
E: [pulseaudio] backend-ofono.c: Failed to register as a handsfree audio agent with ofono: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name is not activatable
```

appears in the log.

I'm on Fedora 31 and have the following package versions

```
Installed Packages
NetworkManager-bluetooth.x86_64              1:1.20.10-1.fc31                    @updates               
bluecurve-cursor-theme.noarch                8.0.2-21.fc31                       @fedora                
bluecurve-icon-theme.noarch                  8.0.2-21.fc31                       @fedora                
blueman.x86_64                               1:2.1.2-1.fc31                      @updates               
bluez-cups.x86_64                            5.54-1.fc31                         @updates               
bluez-libs.x86_64                            5.54-1.fc31                         @updates               
bluez-obexd.x86_64                           5.54-1.fc31                         @updates               
bluez-tools.x86_64                           0.2.0-0.11.git20170912.7cb788c.fc31 @fedora                
bluez.x86_64                                 5.54-1.fc31                         @updates               
gnome-bluetooth-libs.x86_64                  1:3.34.1-1.fc31                     @updates               
gnome-bluetooth.x86_64                       1:3.34.1-1.fc31                     @updates               
pulseaudio-libs-devel.x86_64                 13.99.1-2.fc31 @updates               
pulseaudio-libs-glib2.x86_64                 13.99.1-2.fc31 @updates               
pulseaudio-libs.i686                         13.99.1-2.fc31 @updates               
pulseaudio-libs.x86_64                       13.99.1-2.fc31 @updates               
pulseaudio-module-bluetooth-freeworld.x86_64 1.3-4.fc31     @rpmfusion-free-updates
pulseaudio-module-gsettings.x86_64           13.99.1-2.fc31 @updates               
pulseaudio-module-jack.x86_64                13.99.1-2.fc31 @updates               
pulseaudio-module-x11.x86_64                 13.99.1-2.fc31 @updates               
pulseaudio-utils.x86_64                      13.99.1-2.fc31 @updates               
pulseaudio.x86_64                            13.99.1-2.fc31 @updates
```

My bluetooth device

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
```

EDIT: No news, yet (ordered a new dongle, but that one has exactly the same ID and name), but [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1226169/hsp-hfp-with-0a120001-cambridge-silicon-radio-ltd-bluetooth-dongle-hci-mode) reports the same for Ubuntu.

Comment: Just to clarify, when you change your output configuration to "Headset Head Unit (HSP/HFP)" is when you get issues correct? I have your setup and I had issues until I did the update to the most recent Sony's Firmware version. From time to time, I need to remove the device from the Bluetooth devices, to be able to connect again correctly.

Comment: Exactly. I'm on the latest update, I just checked, but thanks for the suggestion, woudn't have thought of that!

Removing and reconnecting doesn't help ... with "connect again correctly" you mean getting a connection at all? Or the same problem as mine?

Comment: It's simply going to Settings>Bluetooth>Click on the WH-1000 Device> Click on Red Button "Remove Device" then, Disable Bluetooth> Enable Bluetooth > Connect to WH-1000 Device. I know this is not a very advanced solution, but sometimes when I got weird behavior I do this and it comes back to normal. 

Just to mention... I just realized that you have installed the package **pulseaudio-module-bluetooth-freeworld.x86_64 1.3-4.fc31     @rpmfusion-free-update** Do you really need this? I don't use anything from rpmfusion at all.

Comment: That's would I did, but it didn't change anything. I need **pulseaudio-module-bluetooth-freeworld** for the LDAC, aptX etc. support.

Comment: I just tried without this package and the normal **pulseaudio-module-bluetooth** instead, but this led to exactly the same behaviour.

Comment: It works on my laptop, so could it be that the bluetooth adapter has to support it?

Comment: I really don't know the answer to your question. My BT device is integrated with the laptop.
```Vendor: usb 0x8087 "Intel Corp."
Device: usb 0x0a2b```

Comment: Does this seem related to this bug?: **Sound is not coming out on connected bluetooth device** https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1814556

Comment: I have the same problem in Ubuntu 18.04. Any progress on this ?

Comment: It looks like it's my bluetooth adapter. My laptop with exactly the same software versions works as expected.

Comment: @DanielHauck is there a workaround for it? My brand new XPS 13 (9300) has the same problem.

Comment: (If it's any help, I've just dualbooted into Windows where I noticed the same problem. However, a new Bluetooth driver was available and after installing that and rebooting, I could use my WH-1000XM3 with the laptop). No luck on Linux yet (despite kernel 5.7 rc5)

Comment: @bluppfisk Not that I know of ... I also just got a brand new Bluetooth (a cheap Logitech one), but no luck with that one either :-(

Comment: Hello all, you may want to check Pali's work on Pulseaudio. I've been able to use his version to use my Bluetooth headset in HSP/HFP mode even if it's not perfect. https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pulseaudio/pulseaudio/-/merge_requests/288

Comment: I have a similar issue in Arch Linux. Pavucontrol says HSP/HFP is unavailable for a JBL Live400BT. The headset specs say it has support, although.
Tried `pulseaudio-hsphfpd` from AUR but it didn't work.

Comment: @paulodiovani What bluetooth adapter do you use?

Comment: I believe it comes with my Wireless card, listed on `lspci` as `Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to use bluetooth device with HSP/HFP profile using pulseaudio >=6 and bluez >= 5.24](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/341776/how-to-use-bluetooth-device-with-hsp-hfp-profile-using-pulseaudio-6-and-bluez)

Comment: The linked page explicitely says "These steps are here for archival purposes only. Firmware errors on Linux regarding the Bluetooth adapter have no impact on Bluetooth functionality in modern Linux distros". And the ["new" solution](https://kb.plugable.com/questions/680389) only updates to a newer BlueZ version. The problem is not relvant anymore though as Fedora now uses pipewire and with that it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved for me by using pipewire (which is used by default in newer Fedora versions anyways).

Answer (score 0):

I have a USB Bluetooth dongle that uses the same chipset and was able to get it working on Raspbian buster.  A2DP support seems to be pretty good out of the box, but you need HSP/HFP support if you are using a headset.  The following link states something like this:

https://hackaday.io/project/165208-an-old-rotary-phone-as-bluetooth-set/log/162491-setting-up-the-bluetooth

Furthermore, if you find that your headset supports the HFP profile, you will need to install Ofono, as stated in the PulseAudio documentation following:

https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Bluetooth/

I've generalized the scripts that I have, and have posted a link to the GitHub repo:

https://github.com/lmandres/RaspbianBluetoothScripts